# ajax custom header submits twice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, cors

I'm working on an api call to a custom api I built. Works fine with calls being made via curl. But it has issues with Ajax. I understand cors and I believe this may be a cors related issue.

Basically I have a simple ajax call that calls the script and has to send a custom header. When I send the custom header it sends the request twice. At least it shows it on the server side, which stores the api requests. Everytime I call this ajax below, it shows I made two requests. I don't get why it does that.

When I remove the custom header though, it only sends it once.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
                 url: 'https://www.website.com/test.php',
                type: 'GET',   
                beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) { XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("access_token", '1111'); },
                datatype: 'application/json',

                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert('yes');

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('no');
                        console.log( errorThrown );
                }


            }); 
});
```

On the PHP side of things I have the common things specified.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access_token");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

Anyone got any ideas?

UPDATE:
I have attached below two serialized arrays that were both posted to the DB at the exact same time on the same request. One without the custom header, and one with the custom header. I don't understand how this could be happening, preflight shouldn't be posting anything to the DB. I made a similar call to a, near copy of this API and it doesn't post two requests.

Call without the header
    a:11:{s:4:"Host";s:14:"www.websitehere.com";s:10:"Connection";s:10:"keep-   alive";s:13:"Cache-Control";s:9:"max-age=0";s:29:"Access-Control-Request-Method";s:3:"GET";s:6:"Origin";s:20:"http://websitehere.com";s:10:"User-Agent";s:104:"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36";s:30:"Access-Control-Request-Headers";s:20:"accept, access_token";s:6:"Accept";s:3:"*/*";s:7:"Referer";s:34:"http://websitehere.com/test_ajax.php";s:15:"Accept-Encoding";s:19:"gzip, deflate, sdch";s:15:"Accept-Language";s:14:"en-US,en;q=0.8";}

Call with the custom header
    a:9:{s:4:"Host";s:14:"www.websitehere.com";s:10:"Connection";s:10:"keep-    alive";s:6:"Accept";s:3:"*/*";s:6:"Origin";s:20:"http://websitehere.com";s:12:"access_token";s:64:"qUTWcy3qO0Cxc4ffkuU27mmvqyDpLNz4ecB0KTu5PLUllKFb1VhaCbgarfqlDAag";s:10:"User-Agent";s:104:"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36";s:7:"Referer";s:34:"http://websitehere.com/test_ajax.php";s:15:"Accept-Encoding";s:19:"gzip, deflate, sdch";s:15:"Accept-Language";s:14:"en-US,en;q=0.8";}

I did change some of the values of course.

Comment: Post a picture of the requests I believe what you are seeing isn't a double request, you see the options response and the actual request

Comment: I added two serialized arrays to the post. Both are posted to the server at the exact same time on the same request. The arrays are a php getallheaders function and then dumped on to the server to catch what is going on.

Comment: @Geohut Posted an updated if you have any clues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why I finally sat down and tested the difference between the two in jsfiddle. The custom header addition does add in the OPTIONS preflight. I am not sure why it is double calling besides that. The only other possible outcome is a cached version getting called and then after forcing a refresh of the material that can happen if you have a inappropriately configured version of memcache or some other cacheing plugin on your webserver.

Examples of the issue with header
[image: With Header]

Example of the issue without header
[image]

As you can see from the developer tools with the added header it does the preflight options request and without it it receives just the 404.